# How to discovery a bluetooth headset?

Tags: android

I write a sample code to discovery a bluetooth headset(jabra BT2035).
referece http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices

But it can only discovery my notebook computer. If my notebook computer enables bluetooth and sets Enabling discoverability.

The SDK document snippet:

```
android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND"
public static final String ACTION_FOUND
Since: API Level 5
Broadcast Action: Remote device discovered.
Sent when a remote device is found during discovery.
```

I think the remote device means a remote notebook computer except a bluetooth headset.
Could someone please help with this?

thanks alot.
BR,
Perrot

Comment: Did you verify whether the standard build-in Android Bluetooth management activity is able to locate your headset??

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have to put your headset into discoverable mode. Read user manual to your headset. For example my SONY BT headset is only visible for pairing after I hold power button for 5 seconds.

Comment: I have put my headset into discoverable mode.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I can discover a bluetooth headset.
1. When the phone does not pair with a bluetooth headset.
2. Turn headset on - automatic paring mode when LED is lit constantly.

I have another problem. How to check the connection has established between the phone and headset?
Could someone please help with this?

thanks,
perrot